# Convert all fields to UTF8 while querying

Tags: mysql

I needed something like this for querying `latin-2-hungarian-ci` encoded data which I would show on a UTF8 page.

`SELECT CONVERT(* USING utf8) FROM crm_credentials`

What's the right synthax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you will have separately convert all the fields to `UTF-8` like below

```
SELECT CONVERT(col1 USING utf8)
,CONVERT(col2 USING utf8)
FROM tab
```

Else, change the table encoding using `ALTER` statement. See more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

see a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb23a/3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the columns as @Rahul suggested, you are probably better off doing this in your server-side. Assuming you are using PHP, see https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding